# Insert imaginary Rows To CTE Dynamics Construct (use IF EXISTS in dynamics CTE ?)

Tags: t-sql, if-statement, common-table-expression, dynamic-sql

I have below construct dependent on incoming payments.

According to various situations need to adapt the final report (for example, at a certain date establishes the first row is zero, the second displays credit payments deducted from the required cash credit).

I need to construct this CTE adapted to be able to create **IMAGINARY ROWS** depending on various conditions specified in ERP ...

```
 INSERT  INTO @PLATBY
                    ( ROWNUMBER ,
                      OD ,
                      DO ,
                      UHRADA
                    )
                    EXECUTE
                           ( 'WITH PLATBY AS (
                    SELECT
                    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FAK.DATUM),
                    FAK.DATUM,SUM(FAK.CASTKA) AS CASTKA
                    FROM (
                    SELECT FAPLATV.FPV_DATUM AS DATUM,SUM(FAPLATV.FPV_CASTKA) AS CASTKA
                    FROM ' + @DATABASE + '..CG_OP7UC UC
                    INNER JOIN ' + @DATABASE
                             + '..CG_OP7FV FVxCO ON FVxCO.CODE = UC.CODE
                    INNER JOIN ' + @DATABASE
                             + '..CG_POZN POZNAMKA ON POZNAMKA.ID=FVxCO.TYP AND POZNAMKA.ZKRATKA in (''UB'',''UDB'',''UP'',''UDP'')
                    INNER JOIN ' + @DATABASE
                             + '..FAKTURYV FAKTURYV ON FAKTURYV.CISLO_FV = FVxCO.CISLO_FV
                    INNER JOIN ' + @DATABASE
                             + '..FAPLATV FAPLATV ON FAPLATV.FPV_CISLO = FAKTURYV.CISLO_FV
                    WHERE UC.CODE LIKE ''' + @CODE + '''
                    GROUP BY FAPLATV.FPV_DATUM
                    UNION ALL
                    --Pridani Faktur s DPH
                    SELECT FVxCO.DAT AS DATUM,-FAKTURYV.CASTKA AS CASTKA
                    FROM ' + @DATABASE + '..CG_OP7UC UC
                    INNER JOIN ' + @DATABASE
                             + '..CG_OP7FV FVxCO ON FVxCO.CODE = UC.CODE
                    INNER JOIN ' + @DATABASE
                             + '..CG_POZN POZNAMKA ON POZNAMKA.ID=FVxCO.TYP AND POZNAMKA.ZKRATKA in (''UDB'',''UDP'')
                    INNER JOIN ' + @DATABASE
                             + '..FAKTURYV FAKTURYV ON FAKTURYV.CISLO_FV = FVxCO.CISLO_FV
                    WHERE UC.CODE LIKE ''' + @CODE + '''
                    SELECT UC.DATSAZ  AS DATUM, UC.UVER AS CASTKA
                    FROM ' + @DATABASE + '..CG_OP7UC UC
                    WHERE  UC.CODE LIKE ''' + @CODE
                             + '''
                     )FAK
                    GROUP BY FAK.DATUM
                    )
                    SELECT PLATBY.rownum,prev.DATUM AS OD,PLATBY.DATUM as DO,PLATBY.CASTKA AS UHRADA
                    FROM PLATBY
                    LEFT JOIN PLATBY prev ON prev.rownum = PLATBY.rownum - 1
                    LEFT JOIN PLATBY nex ON nex.rownum = PLATBY.rownum + 1
                    '
                           );
```

Comment: I found that the IF EXISTS can't be incorporated to CTE (or the dynamic CTE). How should I systemically treat if the client fulfills certain conditions, at the end of that construct, where systemic incoming payments are counted, two fictitious rows with different among calculation should be inserted (depending on variants, the total approx. 6 variants => 6 different forms of the final SELECT That's why I wanted to use the IF EXISTS CTE)

Comment: I know I will handle the variants of fictional rows through SET, set the value of text variables @ QUERY1 = '' SET @ QUERY2 = '' SET @ QUERY3 = '' SET @ QUERY4 = '' and I will compose them through IF EXIST

Answer (score 0):

```
Resolution: 1. check statement, 2. construct query as string 

SET @sqlstatement = ( 'SELECT @result=CASE 
WHEN UC._DATDOKON IS NULL AND ISNULL(UC.UVER, 0) > 0  THEN 1 
WHEN UC._DATDOKON IS NULL AND ISNULL(UC.UVER, 0) = 0 THEN 2 
WHEN UC._DATDOKON IS NOT NULL AND ISNULL(UC.UVER, 0) > 0 THEN 3
WHEN UC._DATDOKON IS NOT NULL AND ISNULL(UC.UVER, 0) = 0 THEN 4
ELSE 0 END 
FROM    ' + @DATABASE + '..CG_OP7UC UC
INNER JOIN ' + @DATABASE
+ '..FAKTURYV PL ON PL.CODE = UC.CODE
WHERE   UC.CODE LIKE ''' + @CODE + '''' );

SET @parmDefinition = N'@result INT OUTPUT';
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstatement, @parmDefinition,
@result = @EXISTS OUTPUT;

2. construct Query as string:
SET @FQUERY = ISNULL(@QUERYHEADER, '') + ISNULL(@QUERYVER1, '')
+ ISNULL(@QUERYVER2, '') + ISNULL(@QUERYVER3, '')
+ ISNULL(@QUERYVER4, '') + ISNULL(@QUERYFOOTER, '');
PRINT ( @FQUERY );

INSERT  INTO @PLATBY
 ( ROWNUMBER ,
OD ,
DO ,
UHRADA
)
EXECUTE ( @FQUERY);
```